# How to make this query efficient?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization, mariadb

I have a very complex SQL query, which mostly runs fine thanks to index. However, there's a JOIN I don't seem able to make faster.

Simplifying a lot, it could be something like the following:

Table main: id INT;
Table ref: type INT, id1 INT, id2 INT;

In other words, There's a main table with an id field, and another table with two fields id1 and id2.
For some values of type in which I am interested (say t1 AND t2), both id1 and id2 are references to the main table.

The query;

```
SELECT main.id
     , ref.id2 FROM main
  LEFT 
  JOIN ref 
 ON ref.type = t1 
    OR ref.type = t2 
   AND (main.id = ref.id1 OR main.id = ref.id2) 
 WHERE main.id IN (list) 
    OR main.id = ref.id1 
    OR main.id = ref.id2
```

In natural language:
I have a list of Ids. I want all those ids, and for every id1 or id2 in that list, I want the related one.

An example. With the following data:

> main:
>
> - 1..20
>
> ref:
>
> - (1, 15)
> - (20, 2)
> - (3, 5)
> - (12, 17)
>
> LIST:
>
> - 1..5

I would like to retrieve (in any order):

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 15
- 20

I have tried with several indices I thought could help: (type, id1), (type, id2), (type, id1, id2); but to no avail. EXPLAIN says it's using them, but there's no noticeable difference.

As soon as each table has a couple thousand rows, it takes in the order of a second without the list part. With some (large, hundred of elements) lists it seems to take even more.

Why does it takes so much time? Is it possible to make it faster?

I hope it doesn't matter much, but I'm using MariaDb 10.0.16

Comment: You have to `WHERE` clauses, but no `ON` clause...

Comment: `OR`-ed join conditions usually result in bad plans, it's might be better to rewrite to two Selecta plus `UNION`.

Comment: What's `t1` and `t2`, columns or parameters?

Comment: @dnoeth they are parameters.

Comment: @Guest: It's `UNION`, which defaults to `DISTINCT`, not `UNION ALL`. If this is less efficient depends...

Comment: I don't understand the `or` clauses in the outer query.  If you have a list of ids you are interested in, why would you want more?

Comment: I want the items in the list and some related items (which are of the same type).

Comment: You should show some actual data for a better explanation what you try to achieve.

Comment: `OR` is often deadly on performance.  It usually makes it impossible to use indexes.  Reformulate the query without `OR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give performance advice without knowing a lot of specifics about your system. Here's an alternative approach though, which might or might not perform better:

```
SELECT id FROM main WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
UNION
SELECT id2 FROM refs WHERE id1 IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
UNION
SELECT id1 FROM refs WHERE id2 IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to find something obvious I was doing wrong. I hand't thought of using an UNION, guess that could help.

Comment: The query was an awful lot more complex than the provided sample so the change was way harder than I expected, but with UNIONS it runs an order of magnitude faster (with my current data, anyway). It also helped me uncover a nasty bug.